# Next.js Custom HTTP headers in next.config dosent show

Tags: next.js, next.js13, i18next

I am trying to set custom HTTP headers inside next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*{/}?',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'x-hello',
            value: 'world',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  distDir: 'build',
  output: 'export',
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
    // allowFutureImage: true,
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en-PT', 'pt', 'es-ES', 'ch', 'fr-CH', 'it-CH', 'en-CH', 'en-ES'],
    localeDetection: false,
    defaultLocale: 'es-ES',
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      ...config.resolve.fallback,
      fs: false,
      module: false,
    };

    return config;
  }
};
```

but it doesn't work,
for start I need this to show, after that I need to show the locale
nextjs version 12

Comment: It is not working locally or on production?